# storing qr code in google pay(google wallet)

Tags: google-pay, wallet, apple-wallet

Is it possible to store information such as QR code in google pay just like apple wallet ? if not is there any alternative ,I have researched certain apps and haven't got any relevant resource yet

Comment: https://developers.google.com/pay/passes

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Many different types of passes support a [`Barcode`](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/rest/v1/Barcode?hl=en) property where `type` is `QR_CODE`.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/google-pay/gpay-loyaltyapi-demo/blob/935d7a8bf94b3fa821b147d62b56e4501cbc9d14/functions/src/services/loyalty-service.js#L53-L56) on how to set it:

```js
const loyaltyObject = {
  id: getLoyaltyId(email),
  classId: `${issuerId}.${loyaltyProgram}`,
  accountId: email,
  accountName: name,
  state: 'active',
  loyaltyPoints: {
    balance: {
      int: points,
    },
    label: 'Points',
  },
  barcode: {
    type: 'qrCode',
    value: email,
  },
};
```